# Different window for different buttons in Pysimplegui

Tags: pysimplegui

here is my query, so I have a separate button for each of the subject, what I want is for different window to open for a different button. tried it for statistics, didnt help. Please someone help.

here is the code

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
        [sg.Text("Welcome, please select the subject.")],
        [sg.Button("Statistics", key="stat"), sg.Button("Computer Science", key="cs"),
        sg.Button("Mathematics", key="math"), sg.Button("Physics", key="phy"),
        sg.Button("Electronics", key="ele"), sg.Button("Chemistry", key="chem")]]

window = sg.Window("Basic details", layout)

def stats_window():
    layout_s = [[sg.Text("Enter Full Name :"), sg.InputText(key="name")],
                 [sg.Text("Select Subject"), sg.Combo(["Statistics", "Computer Science", "Mathematics", "Electronics",
                                                       "Physics", "Chemistry"], key="subject")],
                 [sg.Text("Enter Enrollment No. :"), sg.InputText(key="rollno")],
                 [sg.Text("Medium :"), sg.InputText(key="med")],
                 [sg.Text("Gender"), sg.Combo(["Male", "Female"], key="gender")],
                 [sg.Button("Submit", key="submit")]

                ]
    stats_window = sg.Window("Statistics", layout_s, modal=True)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break

    window.close()


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Statistics":
        stats_window()

window.close()
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate or give an example. Thank You.

Comment: I am new here how can I share?

Comment: no no i mean how and where I can share, I am unable to attch an image

Comment: okay please help me brother, I tried changing my code, what I did instead is, I made a button for each value, but it is still not working, looking forward to your answer, please look at the code, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

From the code, there are something wrong

- The event is the key of the clicked button. For `sg.Button("Statistics", key="stat")`, it will be `"stat"`, not `"Statistics"`.
- for function `stats_window`, the instance `stats_window` of `sg.Window` is different when you call `window.read()` and `window.close()`

Revised code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def stats_window():

    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Enter Full Name :"),
         sg.InputText(key="name")],
        [sg.Text("Select Subject"),
         sg.Combo(["Statistics", "Computer Science", "Mathematics", "Electronics", "Physics", "Chemistry"], key="subject")],
        [sg.Text("Enter Enrollment No. :"), sg.InputText(key="rollno")],
        [sg.Text("Medium :"), sg.InputText(key="med")],
        [sg.Text("Gender"), sg.Combo(["Male", "Female"], key="gender")],
        [sg.Button("Submit", key="submit")],
    ]
    window = sg.Window("Statistics", layout, modal=True)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
    window.close()

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Welcome, please select the subject.")],
    [sg.Button("Statistics", key="stat"),
     sg.Button("Computer Science", key="cs"),
     sg.Button("Mathematics", key="math"),
     sg.Button("Physics", key="phy"),
     sg.Button("Electronics", key="ele"),
     sg.Button("Chemistry", key="chem")],
]

window = sg.Window("Basic details", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "stat":
        stats_window()

window.close()
```

Comment: Bro, Thank you so very much. I am new to this, working on a project, will try my best to resolve all errors on my own, but if I am not able to, please help me.

Comment: hello, please help me, I posted a question